# Is there any way to make long iterative codes in python not take progressively longer to run as they take on more and more information?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed that some recent code that I was experimenting with to find the digits of pi to many decimals started off running very quickly getting often thousands of decimals per second (might be exaggerated but it was a pretty considerable amount per second), but after it got to around the 10 000 or higher mark of decimals, it would only be adding 50 or so decimals per second.

I've heard before that there are ways to structure your code so that you can have this issue not occur. I'm not sure if it's done by getting rid of the already processed digits or something else.

Some code that could be useful although I'm looking more for a general answer of techniques that I could use rather than one for my specific use case now.

This is the code in order to find the digits:

```
 while counter != decimal + 1:
            if 4 * q + r - t < n * t:
                    # yield digit
                    yield n
                    # insert period after first digit
                    if counter == 0:
                            yield '.'
                    # end
                    if decimal == counter:
                            print('')
                            break
                    counter += 1
                    nr = 10 * (r - n * t)
                    n = ((10 * (3 * q + r)) // t) - 10 * n
                    q *= 10
                    r = nr
            else:
                    nr = (2 * q + r) * l
                    nn = (q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) // (t * l)
                    q *= k
                    t *= l
                    l += 2
                    k += 1
                    n = nn
                    r = nr
```

Code that prints the digits:

```
  for d in pi_digits:
            print(d, end='')
            i += 1
            if i == 100:
                print("")
                i = 0
```

Also, I currently have the digits of pi printing in lines of 100, would I get any speed benefit by reducing or increasing the number of digits in a line so that the code wouldn't have to break lines as often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the 'issue' is with the underlying 'large integer' implementation of python.

If the numbers are small, python can use common 32/64-bit values to represent them, but there's a limit. Since python's aim is to be easy to use, it switches to a custom implementation for numbers larger than that called 'bignum'. Although I'm not sure how python implements this, most BigNum/BigInt/etc implementations use an array to represent each digit. So, if we represent `123` in a bignum structure, we store each digit in a separate item in the array, something like this:

```py
value = [1, 2, 3]
```

This is fine for storing the numbers, but as you can expect, not so great for doing operations. Processors handle really well with 32/64-bit value operations, but they have no idea how to multiply `[1, 2, 3]` with `[6, 2, 1, 5]`. This means there's a lot of python code that is ran in order to handle these operations, and these are slow.

If you're doing this just for fun, leaving as it is, or trying to code the same stuff in a lower level language with a faster BigInt implementation would be my suggestion, but if you really need this code to be fast, whenever there's numbers involved, and you need stuff to run fast, there's probably a [numpy](https://numpy.org/) structure or algorithm that can help you, since it uses C code to run stuff. Search for 'numpy bigint', 'numpy large numbers', etc, and you'll find some way to speed up your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're getting to calculations with bigger and bigger numbers, which take up more space in memory and take longer and longer to carry out calculations with so the code will inevitably take longer to run as it goes on.

Already processed digits are being handled automatically as you are replacing the variables with their new values anyway.

As for the print statements, I doubt it will have any noticeable impact on performance but I recommend the following to replace your current code just for simplicity's sake:

```
print("".join(pi_digits))
```